# How to insert 0 in varbinary(max) field

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert 0 value in varbinary max to test some results. I tried casting '' to binary, tried entering 0 to it but it converts it to 0x00.

Is there a way to enter just 0 for particular value?

Comment: 0x00 is the hexadecimal representation of 0.

Comment: @MattGrande I think OP means an empty byte sequence.

Comment: @MattGrande - is there a way to get just 0?

Comment: It IS just 0. If you say `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyBinaryField = 0`, your row will show up. 0x00 is just how it's displayed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you're looking to represent an empty byte sequence, set its value to `0x`

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyBinary) VALUES (0x)
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (
    binaryField VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @myTable(binaryField) VALUES(0x) -- 0 bytes
INSERT INTO @myTable(binaryField) VALUES(0x11223344) -- 4 bytes

SELECT *, len(binaryField) FROM @myTable
```

Comment: it enters 0x still not just 0.

Comment: I think the problem lies with how you're trying to represent the data in the column, not the storage of the data itself.  `0x` is the representation of an empty byte sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @binaryField VARBINARY(MAX);
SET @binaryField = 0x00000000;
SELECT CONVERT(INT, @binaryField)
```